# What is the getter for child elements of an Array or similar object called

Tags: c#, computer-science

I was wondering when writing some documentation what the type of getter is called.

I mean like, this type of getter

```
public String this[string index]
    {
        get
        {
            return resolveKey(index);
        }
    }
```

Would it be something like a `property accessor` or something?

There is probably some other question on so asking the same thing but because so uses `[]` to group tags and google ignores symbols I can't really search it xD

Comment: The indexer syntax can only be applied to `this` as in `public String this[string index]`

Comment: I started to type the indexer and got to Foo and forgot what I actually wrote. My actually code uses `this`

Comment: @SmartLemon, fair enough, and thanks for correcting.  But as far as SOP goes, please always run code through your compiler before posting it to SO.  (this is for your benefit, as you get the most attention when first posting the question -- attention somewhat invalidated when the code isn't "real")

Comment: real code.... `public dynamic this[dynamic index]...` xD

Comment: @SmartLemon, oh dear.  I suppose I won't bother getting on my high horse and launching into a diatribe about inappropriate usages of `dynamic`.

Comment: Theres no context around it so there is no reason to assume. In the process of changing it.

Comment: @SmartLemon, without context, it can (almost) be safely assumed that `dynamic` is inappropriate.  Almost exactly analogous to using `unsafe`.

Comment: Im just going to leave this :). Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of property is called an Indexer because you are performing an array-style lookup based on an "index" value.

As thoughtfully pointed out in the comments, the `this` keyword must be used to define indexers.

Here's the [MSFT documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx)